# WINBugs: array index is greater than array upper bound

Tags: winbugs

I need help to find the error in my WINBUGS code (v. 1.4.3).

While in the "Model Specification" step, the model looks syntatically correct. However, in my attempt to load the data, I got this error:

**array index is greater than array upper bound for phi3**

Could someone please help me? My model is provided below:

```
model {

        for(w in 1: W){
        m[w] <- n[w]-y1[w]
        h[w] <- n[w]-y1[w]-y2[w]
        y1[w] ~ dbin(delta[w],n[w])
        y2[w] ~ dbin(theta[w],m[w])
        y3[w] ~ dbin(eta[w],h[w])
        y4[w] <- n[w]-y1[w]-y2[w]-y3[w]
        logit(delta[w]) <- mu1+theta1[a[w]]+phi1[p[w]]+psi1[c[w]]
        logit(theta[w]) <- mu2+theta2[a[w]]+phi2[p[w]]+psi2[c[w]]
        logit(eta[w])   <- mu3+theta3[a[w]]+phi3[p[w]]+psi3[c[w]]
    }

    ## Autoregressive prior model for p effects

    phi1mean[1] <- 0.0
    phi1prec[1] <- tauphi1*1.0E-6
    phi1mean[2] <- 0.0
    phi1prec[2] <- tauphi1*1.0E-6

    phi2mean[1] <- 0.0
    phi2prec[1] <- tauphi2*1.0E-6
    phi2mean[2] <- 0.0
    phi2prec[2] <- tauphi2*1.0E-6

    phi3mean[1] <- 0.0
    phi3prec[1] <- tauphi3*1.0E-6
    phi3mean[2] <- 0.0
    phi3prec[2] <- tauphi3*1.0E-6

    phi4mean[1] <- 0.0
    phi4prec[1] <- tauphi4*1.0E-6
    phi4mean[2] <- 0.0
    phi4prec[2] <- tauphi4*1.0E-6

    for (j in 3:JJ) {
        phi1mean[j] <- 2*phi1[j-1]-phi1[j-2]
        phi1prec[j] <- tauphi1
        phi2mean[j] <- 2*phi2[j-1]-phi2[j-2]
        phi2prec[j] <- tauphi2
        phi3mean[j] <- 2*phi3[j-1]-phi3[j-2]
        phi3prec[j] <- tauphi3
        phi4mean[j] <- 2*phi4[j-1]-phi4[j-2]
        phi4prec[j] <- tauphi4
    }

    # Sampling p effects and subtracting mean for observed p

    for (j in 1:JJ) {
        phi1[j] ~ dnorm(phi1mean[j],phi1prec[j])
        phi2[j] ~ dnorm(phi2mean[j],phi2prec[j])
        phi3[j] ~ dnorm(phi3mean[j],phi3prec[j])
        phi4[j] ~ dnorm(phi4mean[j],phi4prec[j])
        phi1c[j]    <- phi1[j]-mean(phi1[1:J]) 
        phi2c[j]    <- phi2[j]-mean(phi2[1:J]) 
        phi3c[j]    <- phi3[j]-mean(phi3[1:J]) 
        phi4c[j]    <- phi4[j]-mean(phi4[1:J]) 
    }


    # Hyppriors for the precision parameters

        tauphi1 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tauphi2 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tauphi3 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tauphi4 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        sigmaphi1 <- 1/sqrt(tauphi1)
        sigmaphi2 <- 1/sqrt(tauphi2)
        sigmaphi3 <- 1/sqrt(tauphi3)
        sigmaphi4 <- 1/sqrt(tauphi4)

    ## Autoregressive prior model for c effects

    psi1mean[1] <- 0.0
    psi1prec[1] <- taupsi1*1.0E-6
    psi1mean[2] <- 0.0
    psi1prec[2] <- taupsi1*1.0E-6

    psi2mean[1] <- 0.0
    psi2prec[1] <- taupsi2*1.0E-6
    psi2mean[2] <- 0.0
    psi2prec[2] <- taupsi2*1.0E-6

    psi3mean[1] <- 0.0
    psi3prec[1] <- taupsi3*1.0E-6
    psi3mean[2] <- 0.0
    psi3prec[2] <- taupsi3*1.0E-6

    psi4mean[1] <- 0.0
    psi4prec[1] <- taupsi4*1.0E-6
    psi4mean[2] <- 0.0
    psi4prec[2] <- taupsi4*1.0E-6

    for (l in 3:LL) {
        psi1mean[l] <- 2*psi1[l-1]-psi1[l-2]
        psi1prec[l] <- taupsi1
        psi2mean[l] <- 2*psi2[l-1]-psi2[l-2]
        psi2prec[l] <- taupsi2
        psi3mean[l] <- 2*psi3[l-1]-psi3[l-2]
        psi3prec[l] <- taupsi3
        psi4mean[l] <- 2*psi4[l-1]-psi4[l-2]
        psi4prec[l] <- taupsi4
    }

    # Sampling c effects and subtracting mean for observed c

    for (l in 1:LL) {
        psi1[l]     ~ dnorm(psi1mean[l],psi1prec[l])
        psi2[l]     ~ dnorm(psi2mean[l],psi2prec[l])
        psi3[l]     ~ dnorm(psi3mean[l],psi3prec[l])
        psi4[l]     ~ dnorm(psi4mean[l],psi4prec[l])
        psi1c[l]    <- psi1[l]-mean(psi1[1:L]) 
        psi2c[l]    <- psi2[l]-mean(psi2[1:L]) 
        psi3c[l]    <- psi3[l]-mean(psi3[1:L]) 
        psi4c[l]    <- psi4[l]-mean(psi4[1:L]) 
    }

    # Hyppriors for the precision parameters

        taupsi1 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        taupsi2 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        taupsi3 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        taupsi4 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        sigmapsi1 <- 1/sqrt(taupsi1)
        sigmapsi2 <- 1/sqrt(taupsi2)
        sigmapsi3 <- 1/sqrt(taupsi3)
        sigmapsi4 <- 1/sqrt(taupsi4)

    ## Autoregressive prior model for a effects

    theta1mean[1] <- 0.0
    theta1prec[1] <- tautheta1*1.0E-6
    theta1mean[2] <- 0.0
    theta1prec[2] <- tautheta1*1.0E-6

    theta2mean[1] <- 0.0
    theta2prec[1] <- tautheta2*1.0E-6
    theta2mean[2] <- 0.0
    theta2prec[2] <- tautheta2*1.0E-6

    theta3mean[1] <- 0.0
    theta3prec[1] <- tautheta3*1.0E-6
    theta3mean[2] <- 0.0
    theta3prec[2] <- tautheta3*1.0E-6

    theta4mean[1] <- 0.0
    theta4prec[1] <- tautheta4*1.0E-6
    theta4mean[2] <- 0.0
    theta4prec[2] <- tautheta4*1.0E-6

    for (i in 3:I) {
        theta1mean[i] <- 2*theta1[i-1]-theta1[i-2]
        theta1prec[i] <- tautheta1
        theta2mean[i] <- 2*theta2[i-1]-theta2[i-2]
        theta2prec[i] <- tautheta2
        theta3mean[i] <- 2*theta3[i-1]-theta3[i-2]
        theta3prec[i] <- tautheta3
        theta4mean[i] <- 2*theta4[i-1]-theta4[i-2]
        theta4prec[i] <- tautheta4
    }

    # Sampling a effects

    for (i in 1:I) {
        theta1[i] ~ dnorm(theta1mean[i],theta1prec[i])
        theta2[i] ~ dnorm(theta2mean[i],theta2prec[i])
        theta3[i] ~ dnorm(theta3mean[i],theta3prec[i])
        theta4[i] ~ dnorm(theta4mean[i],theta4prec[i])
    }

    # Hyppriors for the precision parameters

        tautheta1 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tautheta2 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tautheta3 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        tautheta4 ~ dgamma(1.0E-1,1.0E-1)
        sigmatheta1 <- 1/sqrt(tautheta1)
        sigmatheta2 <- 1/sqrt(tautheta2)
        sigmatheta3 <- 1/sqrt(tautheta3)
        sigmatheta4 <- 1/sqrt(tautheta4)

    # Removing linear trends from a
    for (i in 1:I) {
        ivec1[i]    <- i-(I+1)/2
        aivec1[i]   <- ivec1[i]*theta1[i]
        theta1c[i]  <- theta1[i]-ivec1[i]*sum(aivec1[])/(I*(I+1)*(I-1)/12)
        ivec2[i]    <- i-(I+1)/2
        aivec2[i]   <- ivec2[i]*theta2[i]
        theta2c[i]  <- theta2[i]-ivec2[i]*sum(aivec2[])/(I*(I+1)*(I-1)/12)
        ivec3[i]    <- i-(I+1)/2
        aivec3[i]   <- ivec3[i]*theta3[i]
        theta3c[i]  <- theta3[i]-ivec3[i]*sum(aivec3[])/(I*(I+1)*(I-1)/12)
        ivec4[i]    <- i-(I+1)/2
        aivec4[i]   <- ivec4[i]*theta4[i]
        theta4c[i]  <- theta4[i]-ivec4[i]*sum(aivec4[])/(I*(I+1)*(I-1)/12)
    }

    ## Computing fitted and projected probabilities
    for (i in 1:I) { 
        for (j in 1:JJ) { 
            deltapred[i,j]      <- exp(mu1+theta1[i]+phi1[j]+psi1[I+j-i])
            thetapred[i,j]      <- exp(mu2+theta2[i]+phi2[j]+psi2[I+j-i])
            etapred[i,j]        <- exp(mu3+theta3[i]+phi3[j]+psi3[I+j-i])
            p1[i,j]             <- deltapred[i,j]   
            p2[i,j]             <- thetapred[i,j]*(1-deltapred[i,j])
            p3[i,j]             <- etapred[i,j]*(1-deltapred[i,j])*(1-thetapred[i,j]) 
            p4[i,j]             <- (1-deltapred[i,j])*(1-thetapred[i,j]-etapred[i,j]+(etapred[i,j]*thetapred[i,j])) 
        }
    }
}

### Data

list(
y1=c(1538727,1444672,1206999,1002960,744597,390301,1640130,1472255,1383947,1109395,984775,697701,1769569,1573498,1489025,1351284,1111397,935166,1747764,1790841,1626852,1407388,1284583,995236,1676555,1787181,1655400,1527122,1421772,1309989,1561922,1643467,1598855,1570645,1495999,1319439,1456258,1561892,1567872,1555237,1551579,1532222,1243436,1387943,1436659,1511134,1549578,1539580),
y2=c(2634569,3031916,3138776,2875868,2495888,1886174,2148776,2567507,2747428,2696199,2593985,2138303,1662296,2224336,2489723,2698322,2655746,2450716,1304387,1734318,2180203,2396749,2629088,2555934,1087351,1380119,1616309,2109287,2408800,2369855,821642,1041702,1221283,1661647,2098345,2426842,708327,873092,952245,1237084,1628334,2123709,549763,666699,774205,981393,1243888,1538431),
y3=c(1245931,1664176,1659375,2313647,3850196,4254634,825634,1293382,1454776,1736181,2596719,3655532,554953,901957,1186747,1490664,2083400,2738988,335824,630232,847486,1239538,1702256,2296941,218213,373786,555286,907876,1397221,2005940,143202,237344,344229,594993,1012777,1510283,121187,151070,219731,351040,650930,1157146,87211,120279,140551,226530,393887,733699),
n=c(5862309,6673625,6534802,6942747,8329067,8152696,5049199,5913474,6268113,6253757,7298375,8260640,4319559,5245545,5840408,6306245,6785242,7492958,3588778,4553684,5259609,5813653,6517271,7001560,3105173,3797508,4271831,5180290,6086716,7002991,2591140,3063506,3428373,4305319,5326889,6217360,2329398,2661972,2886111,3418403,4327922,5565798,1906676,2224544,2444586,2864892,3473404,4362648),
a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8),
p=c(9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14),
c=c(8,9,10,11,12,13,7,8,9,10,11,12,6,7,8,9,10,11,5,6,7,8,9,10,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6),
W=48,
I=8,
J=6,
JJ=8,
L=13,
LL=15
)


# Inits
list( 
tauphi1=1,
tauphi2=1,
tauphi3=1,
tauphi4=1,
taupsi1=1,
taupsi2=1,
taupsi3=1,
taupsi4=1,
tautheta1=1,
tautheta2=1,
tautheta3=1,
tautheta4=1,
theta1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
theta2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
theta3=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
theta4=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
phi1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
phi2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
phi3=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
phi4=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
psi1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
psi2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
psi3=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
psi4=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the definition of logit(eta[w]) you have used phi3[p[w]], and p[w] takes values from 9 to 14. But definitions of phi3[j] are only given for j = 1 to JJ=8.  Hence "the array index (9 to 14) is greater than the array upper bound (8)"